# DispatchQueue freezed main queue

Tags: swift, dispatch-queue, dispatchgroup

I need to do some methods one by one without interrupting, in a separate thread, that way I have in my class

```
fileprivate var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "ProgressHUD", qos: .userInteractive)
```

and when I need show/hide I do some like this

```
queue.sync {
    __hide()
}
```

or

```
queue.sync {
    __show()
}
```

in this `__%%()` methods, I need to do some actions with UI in the main thread, and I need to do all action from --show/--hide one by one without interrupting. So in inner, I use

```
private func __show()
{
    let g = DispatchGroup()
    g.enter()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("go?")
        self.doMyAction1()
        self.doMyAction2()
        self.doMyAction3()

        g.leave()
    }
    g.wait()
}
```

but the app always freezes on line `g.wait()` and doesn't call `main.async` and doesn't print `go?`. What I do wrong!?

Answer (score 0):

```
func dispatchGroup() -> String {

   var message = ""

   let group = DispatchGroup()

   group.enter()

   DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        message = "Hiii Friends"
        group.leave()
   }

   group.wait()

   return message
}
```

Comment: I already read this thread before my post (where you copy-pasted text), but not understand what I do wrong?